# Position absolute and relative on one element?

Tags: css, css-position

I want to position a div relative to it's parent div and also give this div a position: relative; so that it's children elements get positioned to this element.

I've not tested it my self, but is it possible? and what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Try it and come back if you have any problems.

Comment: Can you tell me how please?

Comment: Maybe try testing it yourself? Jsfiddle is a good tool.

Comment: create a fiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8HBP8/

Comment: Sameer how about showing us the codes which didn't work? I'm glad they put this topic on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Make your first div `position:relative` and the next 2 divs `position:absolute`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8HBP8/)**

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.one
{
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
.two
{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: pink;
}
.three
{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: brown;
}
```

Comment: Ugh. I don't want to be high-and-mighty, but when a person is blatantly not thinking for themselves, don't just spoon feed them an answer. By all means point them in the right direction, but by doing this you just encourage them to come back with their next "how to I check if x and y are the same number?"

Comment: Dave is right. Don't answer questions who don't give a clue

Comment: I'm glad I'm not alone in this opinion. I don't think it's high and mighty to tell someone that the OP needs to put some effort into their own problem instead of using a copypasta answer

Comment: Fair enough, the asker really should have tried this himself, but I think that if an answer itself could be useful to others (not everyone is well versed in css) then it is justified.

Comment: Well I don't know why so many think that I'm not putting an effort myself, I've tried a lot that's why I asked here. By tested it myself I meant to say that I've not successfully gotten it to work (giving absolute and relative position to the same element). But thank you very much for this answer, I've got the trick now.

Comment: @Danield this answer has appeared in many other places. Anybody doing a quick search would find them, which the OP clearly didn't do. It's just something to consider in the future; if more people told these askers to think for themselves, maybe they would start actually thinking for themselves.

Comment: @SameerZahid then in future please post what you tried that didn't work. It takes very little to turn a bad question into a good question. You just need to show that you have actually put some effort in, but have reached a point where you don't know what to do. That way, we can also suggest new problem solving methods to you which would help in similar situations.

Comment: @SameerZahid: if you don’t *show us* what you’ve tried, then 1. we don’t know that you’ve tried it, but more importantly, 2. we don’t know how best to answer you, because we don’t know what your misunderstanding is.

Comment: @SameerZahid: The proper format for a question like this is: 1. Here’s what I’m trying to achieve. 2. Here’s the code I’ve written to try to achieve that. 3. Here’s what I think that code should do. 4. Here’s what that code actually does. That way, we (and anyone looking at your question in future) have got all the information about the problem you’re experiencing, and can put our effort into helping instead of guessing. When you don’t include those details, it feels like you can’t be bothered putting in the effort to ask a good question, but expect us to put in effort to help you.

Comment: I understand what you guys mean, but really the question is so fundamental and so basic, what do u expect me to provide u. It's not something complex like creating a slider or an effect, where I can show my progress and others can suggest where I go from there. I tried making it both position: absolute and position: relative, but it didn't work. I searched on Google a lot, but I didn't find an answer. That's when I came here to ask. But I guess I should have made it clear in the question, will keep that in mind in the future, thank you.